# Right way to set geometry properties of a window

Tags: c++, qt

I'm refactoring some old code and i just find out that `QDesktopWidget::availableGeometry` has been deprecated in favor of `QGuiApplication:screens()`.
 I used the following code to set geometry properties of a window(in particular to align it to the center of the screen) but now it doesn't works anymore.

```cpp
    win.setGeometry(
        QStyle::alignedRect(
            Qt::LeftToRight,
            Qt::AlignCenter,
            win.size(),
            qApp->desktop()->availableGeometry() // deprecated
        )
    );
```

What changes i have to make in order to use screens method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are on the first screen then you must use:

```
qApp->primaryScreen()->availableGeometry();
```

If you are on the nth screen:

```
qApp->screens().at(n)->availableGeometry();
```